# Make the column header bold while converting from JSON to CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I am trying to export JSON Object to CSV and for that I am using Code which is in below fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/light/

```
if (ShowLabel) {
    var row = "";

    //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
    for (var index in arrData[0]) {

        //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
        row += index + ',';
    }

    row = row.slice(0, -1);

    //append Label row with line break
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
}
```

The issue is that I want a bold column header in generated CSV (i.e. in above code , label row contains all column headers which i want in bolt letters). Can someone please help me how its possible using JavaScript?
You can also check the code in below link..

http://www.hybridplanet.co.in/tutorial/javascript/how-to-create-csv-or-excel-file-from-json-via-javascript

Thanx in advance guys.

Comment: what do you mean by "bold column header"?

Comment: i mean the first row of CSV contains column header , i want all those coloumn to be bold.

Comment: How are you going to show that CSV? ... In a webpage?

Comment: @LGSon i am using open Office 4

Comment: I posted an answer how to edit it, can't say if OpenOffice support the `<b>` tag but probably ... try it and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way! This method works perfectly.
Create tableExport.js

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        tableExport: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                    separator: ',',
                    ignoreColumn: [],
                    tableName:'yourTableName',
                    type:'csv',
                    pdfFontSize:14,
                    pdfLeftMargin:20,
                    escape:'true',
                    htmlContent:'false',
                    consoleLog:'false'
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            var el = this;

            if(defaults.type == 'excel') {
                //console.log($(this).html());
                var excel = "<table>";
                // Header
                $(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function () {
                    excel += "<tr>";
                    $(this).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function (index, data) {
                        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                            if (defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1) {
                                excel += "<td><b>" + parseString($(this)) + "</b></td>";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    excel += '</tr>';
                });
                // Row Vs Column
                var rowCount = 1;
                $(el).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function () {
                    excel += "<tr>";
                    var colCount = 0;
                    $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function (index, data) {
                        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                            if (defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1) {
                                excel += "<td>" + parseString($(this)) + "</td>";
                            }
                        }
                        colCount++;
                    });
                    rowCount++;
                    excel += '</tr>';
                });
                excel += '</table>'
                if (defaults.consoleLog == 'true') {
                    console.log(excel);
                }
                var excelFile = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:" + defaults.type + "' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>";
                excelFile += "<head>";
                excelFile += "<!--[if gte mso 9]>";
                excelFile += "<xml>";
                excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorkbook>";
                excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorksheets>";
                excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorksheet>";
                excelFile += "<x:Name>";
                excelFile += "{worksheet}";
                excelFile += "</x:Name>";
                excelFile += "<x:WorksheetOptions>";
                excelFile += "<x:DisplayGridlines/>";
                excelFile += "</x:WorksheetOptions>";
                excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorksheet>";
                excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorksheets>";
                excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorkbook>";
                excelFile += "</xml>";
                excelFile += "<![endif]-->";
                excelFile += "</head>";
                excelFile += "<body>";
                excelFile += excel;
                excelFile += "</body>";
                excelFile += "</html>";
                var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(excelFile);
                //window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-'+defaults.type+';filename=exportData.doc;' + base64data); //this was original

                // Now the little tricky part.(By shreedhar)
                // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
                // but this will not work in some browsers
                // or you will not get the correct file extension
                var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;' + base64data;
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = uri;
                link.style = "visibility:hidden";
                link.download =  "fileName";
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }

            function parseString(data){
                if(defaults.htmlContent == 'true'){
                    content_data = data.html().trim();
                }else{
                    content_data = data.text().trim();
                }
                if(defaults.escape == 'true'){
                    content_data = escape(content_data);
                }
                return content_data;
            }
            //Check oriinal template for lot of convertion like to xml,json,pdf,etc
        }
    });
    })(jQuery);
```

Your HTML will be

```
<table id="customers2" class="table datatable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Base Pack</th>
        <th>Basis</th>
        <th>Weightage</th>
        <th>Error Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="$('#customers2').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"></button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_tableExport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_base64.js"></script>
```

Please check the line which calls parseString function, here b tag will make the headers bold.

You also will be needing base64.js file. Trust me its the standard way.
base64.js

```
jQuery.base64 = ( function( $ ) {

var _PADCHAR = "=",
  _ALPHA = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",
  _VERSION = "1.0";


function _getbyte64( s, i ) {
  // This is oddly fast, except on Chrome/V8.
  // Minimal or no improvement in performance by using a
  // object with properties mapping chars to value (eg. 'A': 0)

  var idx = _ALPHA.indexOf( s.charAt( i ) );

  if ( idx === -1 ) {
    throw "Cannot decode base64";
  }

  return idx;
}


function _decode( s ) {
  var pads = 0,
    i,
    b10,
    imax = s.length,
    x = [];

  s = String( s );

  if ( imax === 0 ) {
    return s;
  }

  if ( imax % 4 !== 0 ) {
    throw "Cannot decode base64";
  }

  if ( s.charAt( imax - 1 ) === _PADCHAR ) {
    pads = 1;

    if ( s.charAt( imax - 2 ) === _PADCHAR ) {
      pads = 2;
    }

    // either way, we want to ignore this last block
    imax -= 4;
  }

  for ( i = 0; i < imax; i += 4 ) {
    b10 = ( _getbyte64( s, i ) << 18 ) | ( _getbyte64( s, i + 1 ) << 12 ) | ( _getbyte64( s, i + 2 ) << 6 ) | _getbyte64( s, i + 3 );
    x.push( String.fromCharCode( b10 >> 16, ( b10 >> 8 ) & 0xff, b10 & 0xff ) );
  }

  switch ( pads ) {
    case 1:
      b10 = ( _getbyte64( s, i ) << 18 ) | ( _getbyte64( s, i + 1 ) << 12 ) | ( _getbyte64( s, i + 2 ) << 6 );
      x.push( String.fromCharCode( b10 >> 16, ( b10 >> 8 ) & 0xff ) );
      break;

    case 2:
      b10 = ( _getbyte64( s, i ) << 18) | ( _getbyte64( s, i + 1 ) << 12 );
      x.push( String.fromCharCode( b10 >> 16 ) );
      break;
  }

  return x.join( "" );
}


function _getbyte( s, i ) {
  var x = s.charCodeAt( i );

  if ( x > 255 ) {
    throw "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5";
  }

  return x;
}


function _encode( s ) {
  if ( arguments.length !== 1 ) {
    throw "SyntaxError: exactly one argument required";
  }

  s = String( s );

  var i,
    b10,
    x = [],
    imax = s.length - s.length % 3;

  if ( s.length === 0 ) {
    return s;
  }

  for ( i = 0; i < imax; i += 3 ) {
    b10 = ( _getbyte( s, i ) << 16 ) | ( _getbyte( s, i + 1 ) << 8 ) | _getbyte( s, i + 2 );
    x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( b10 >> 18 ) );
    x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( ( b10 >> 12 ) & 0x3F ) );
    x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( ( b10 >> 6 ) & 0x3f ) );
    x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( b10 & 0x3f ) );
  }

  switch ( s.length - imax ) {
    case 1:
      b10 = _getbyte( s, i ) << 16;
      x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( b10 >> 18 ) + _ALPHA.charAt( ( b10 >> 12 ) & 0x3F ) + _PADCHAR + _PADCHAR );
      break;

    case 2:
      b10 = ( _getbyte( s, i ) << 16 ) | ( _getbyte( s, i + 1 ) << 8 );
      x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( b10 >> 18 ) + _ALPHA.charAt( ( b10 >> 12 ) & 0x3F ) + _ALPHA.charAt( ( b10 >> 6 ) & 0x3f ) + _PADCHAR );
      break;
  }

  return x.join( "" );
}


return {
  decode: _decode,
  encode: _encode,
  VERSION: _VERSION
};

  }( jQuery ) );
```